# Navbar Overflow issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html {
  overflow: scroll;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}

.logotop {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.logotop p {
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logotop img {
  width: 15vh;
  height: 8vh;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 23px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .logotop p {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:968px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .logotop p {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30vh;
    top: 16vh;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
  .logotop p {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: +1;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logotop">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="./images/logo.jpeg" alt="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="heating.html">HEATING</a></li>
    <li><a href="plumbing.html">PLUMBING</a></li>
    <li><a href="drainage.html">DRAINAGE</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Navbar is overflowing]

I cannot seem to stop the navbar from overflowing on mobile screen the scroll is always available or visible. Please help.

When on a mobile device you can drag or scroll right and see the overlay for the transition. I've tried to make it nonvisible on mobile, but it seems to continually reappear.

I need to fix the code to stop it from being available unless in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should change your transform like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
 .nav-links {
   transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(0); /* in your code scale dose not exist */ 
 }
}
```